# Where is the "Home Computer" information that prevents syncing with other libraries stored on an iPod Classic?

Tags: ipod, ipod-classic

The iPod Classic (and maybe others?) refuses to sync with more than one iTunes library at a time. This is very frustrating when I keep my music on multiple computers.

Where is the "Home Computer" information stored on the iPod? Is it a file? If so where in the iPod filesystem does it live?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to do this successfully suing `rsync` to copy my `~/Music/iTunes/` directory from my "Home Computer" to other computers. I don't remember exactly where the magic is, but it *is* within iTune's metadata.

Once you sync the first time you don't ever *need* to sync again. The libraries can diverge after that and your iPod will still consider them both to be the same library.